# How do I hide spinner, which is in ToolBar, when activity is initially loaded?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I want to make a spinner disappear for certain fragments, but when the activity is first loaded into the default fragment, the spinner is visible instead of gone. I've tried putting it in onCreateOptionsMenu and onCreate but those didn't work. The spinner is in a separate menu from the actual toolbar menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_toolbar, menu);  //only contains icons 
    //which leads to intent of another activity and search

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_toolbar_spinner, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner_toolbar_main);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) item.getActionView();
    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.array_spinner_topics, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    return true;
}
```

And this is the toolbar's spinner's menu (menu tag is per usual xmlns)

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_spinner_toolbar_main"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    tools:ignore="MenuTitle" />
```

Comment: you can set  setHasOptionsMenu(false); in onCreateMethod of the fragment where you don't want to show menus.

Comment: Wouldn't that also get rid of the other icons in the toolbar since it's a separate menu from the spinner?

Comment: yes it will hide all other menus also... check this https://droidmentor.com/how-to-use-fragment-specific-menu-in-android/ for references

Answer (score 0):

First in the xml, I added

```
android:visible="false"
```

Then in the activity, I wrote

```
private int fragNumber = 1;
```

Below the onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected, I started an onPrepareOptionsMenu

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
  MenuItem spinner = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner_toolbar_main);
  if (fragNumber == 1) {
     spinner.setVisible(false);
  } else {
     spinner.setVisible(true);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Then in onNavigationItemSelected, where I have a a fragment loader function embedded inside, I set fragNumber to either 1 or 2.